# Displaying an integer in a pattern using % operator

Tags: c

taking an integer number as input from user and displaying it in the following way 
5678
678
78
8

my code is working for 4 digit  numbers but for 5 digit numbers it is giving wrong output

```
main()
{
int i,reqpow,n,x,rem,temp;
printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf("%d",&n);

temp=n;
int digit=0;
while(temp!=0)
{
    temp=temp/10;
    digit++;
}
reqpow=digit-1;
printf("\n\n%d\n",n);
 for(i=pow(10,reqpow);i>1;i=i/10)
 {
     rem=0;
     rem=n%i;
     printf("%d\n",rem);
 }

}
```

[Wrong output for 12345](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0Xb9.png)

[correct ouput for 123456](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlXZq.png)

Comment: Where is the definition of `digit`?

Comment: missed it while pasting the code now its there

Comment: _"code is working for 4 digit numbers but for 5 digit numbers it is giving wrong output"_ and _"correct ouput for 123456"_. The heuristic guess is that you get correct result for even digits input. Does it give any hint to you?

Comment: also for 3 and 8 digit number  the output is wrong

Comment: where those 3 and 8 digit inputs of the same pattern (123 and 12345678)?

Comment: `int pow10(int n){
 int result = 1;
 for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  result *= 10;
 return result;
}` instead of `pow`.

Comment: no any 3 or 8 digit number

Comment: @mvidelgauz it was an issue with my compiler code-blocks and turbo c.     I tried to compile it online and its working.But still dont know the reason why code-blocks is behaving like this. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main() 
{
 int i,reqpow,n,x,rem,temp;
 printf("Enter a number: ");
 scanf("%d",&n);

 temp=n;
 int digit=0;
 while(temp!=0)
{
 temp=temp/10;
 digit++;
 }
reqpow=digit-1;
printf("\n\n%d\n",n);
for(i=pow(10,reqpow);i>1;i=i/10)
{
 rem=0;
 rem=n%i;
 printf("%d\n",rem);
  }
  return 0;
  }
```

i run your code on Dev-cpp compiler it give output as you requied.

Comment: I'm using codeblocks. What was your output for 12345678??

Comment: yes bro . you should check on other compiler https://www.codechef.com/ide

Comment: i tried it with codechef compiler.It is giving correct output but with codeblocks and turbo c its not.Still dont know the reason for codeblocks to show wrong op.

Comment: @MS1018 every compiler design differently so, different compiler give some time different output because their designer is different .